# ES6 destructuring get nested object property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have below object in an array.
When iterating I need to access a specific property in the loop. I am able to fetch basic properties but unable to get nested property value.

```
let data = [{
  id:"0",
  value:{
    empId:"123",
    emp_type:"perm",
    schedule:{
      abcSchedule:{cron_str: "0 13 * * 0,3,4,5,6"}
    }
  }
}];


var newMap = data.map(({ idx: i, value: { empId, emp_type, /*cron_str ? how to get  */  } }) => console.log(emp_type));
```

How could I get the cron_str when in map with the help of destructuring. If no values is provided then it should have default value.

Comment: You have already destrcutured the nested `empId` and `emp_type`. Have you tried doing the same for `schedule`, `abcSchedule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{value:{schedule:{abcSchedule:{cron_str}}}}`:

```js
let data = [{
    id: "0",
    value: {
      empId: "123",
      emp_type: "perm",
      schedule: {
        abcSchedule: {
          cron_str: "0 13 * * 0,3,4,5,6"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    value: {
      empId: "1234",
      emp_type: "merm",
      schedule: {
        abcSchedule: {
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    value: {
      empId: "1235",
      emp_type: "mtermerm",
      schedule: {
        abcSchedule: {
          cron_str: null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    value: {
      empId: "12356",
      emp_type: "apple",
      schedule: {
        abcSchedule: {
          cron_str: undefined
        }
      }
    }
  }
];


var newMap = data.map(({
  value: {
    empId,
    emp_type,
    schedule: {
      abcSchedule: {
        cron_str
      }
    }
  }
}) => console.log(empId, cron_str));
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i handle undefined cron_str ?

Comment: @user804401 It does handle the `undefined ` and `null` values for `cron_str`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var newMap = data.map(({ idx: i, value: { empId, emp_type, schedule: { abcSchedule: { cron_str }}} }) => console.log(emp_type, cron_str));
```

Just destructure as you did with `value`already.

Comment: Thanks, how can i handle undefined cron_str